# Specific database provider for specific dbcontext using AbpFramework

Tags: abp

Is there a way to specify which provider use for a specific EF DbContext. For example:

DbContext1 -> MySQL

DbContext2 -> SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

DBMS selection is done in the startup template. You can [see here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/MyProjectNameEntityFrameworkCoreModule.cs#L48).

So, you can configure it in `YourProjectNameEntityFrameworkCoreModule` class.

```cs
Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer();
});
```

This code configures ALL dbcontexts in the application. You can configure each DbContext separately with the syntax given below:

```cs
Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Configure<MyProjectNameDbContext>(opts =>
    {
        opts.UseSqlServer();
    });
    
    options.Configure<SecondDbContext>(opts =>
    {
        opts.UseMySql();
    });
});
```

Surely, you need to add [Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) package to your project before calling the `UseMySql()` extension method. See [the documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Other-DBMS) to learn to use other DBMSs.